# How can I use reflection in C# to get object value from a member of a class?

Tags: c#, reflection, subclass

How can I use reflection in C# to get object value from a member of a class ?

I have:

```
public class Class1 {
   public int field1;
   public String field2;
}

public class Class2 {
   public ind code;
   public Class1 classRef;
}
```

I want get the list of members the "classRef" value.

Comment: It's not clear what you want - the value of `classRef` given an instance of `Class2`, or the values of all the fields of `Class1`, given an instance of that class.

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection? What problems are you trying to solve? If the members are public; just access them.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is close

```
var c2 = new Class2 
                { 
                  code = 3; 
                  Class1 = new Class1 
                  {
                      field1 = 7; 
                      field2 = "class 1"
                  }
                };

var fields = c2.GetType().GetFields();
var field = fields.Where(fi=>fi.Name == "classRef").FirstOrDefault();
Assert.True(field != null);
var value = field.GetValue(c2) as Class1;

Assert.True(value != null);
Assert.True(value.field1 == 7);
Assert.True(value.field2 == "class 1");
```